# How can i integrate Jenkins with Onedrive?

Tags: jenkins, devops

I would like to integrate Jenkins with OneDrive to upload data's. I had a look at the Jenkins available plugins. But there is no OneDrive plugin to integrate. Is this possible to integrate? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add code in some way, either bash / cmd / your-favorite-langauge and upload using the [onedrive api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/upload?view=odsp-graph-online)

You should first attempt to do it locally, with a script or a few commands - later translate that into your Jenkins.

This is also best practice, you should stay away from Jenkins plugins since they are community driven. Unless the quality of life improvement is worth it.